# Express/node requestor ip

Tags: node.js, express, ip

I am trying to build an API that returns different things for different ip addresses. For example, a certain domain that redirects to my server (say google.com) will be shown one thing, and another domain (say amazon.com) would show something different.

I have tried using middleware that looks at req.ip, but it seems like req.ip always returns "::ffff:127.0.0.1" from any request. Additionally, I would like to limit connections via the last jump to my server - i.e. show different content based on website.com, where:
client browser -> website.com -> my server.

How would I go about doing this using Express.js

**EDIT**: I think people are misunderstanding my question: I do not want to filter my results by the client's ip. I want to filter results by the last bounce to my server. I.e. if a client connects to redirect.com and redirect forwards to my server, I want to detect the ip of redirect.com and filter based on that. Say there is another site called fam.com that forwards to my server also. I want to display different things to fam.com than to redirect.com.

Comment: Do you use any sort of proxy? if so you need to configure your proxy to forward ip

Comment: would req.ip in express then return the  originating address of the request or the most proximate bounce?

Comment: Please see if 'refferer' header is set if you are using proxy. Otherwise try to send the IP as a variable from the client.

Comment: I don't want the behavior to trigger from the client. I want the content to vary by the second to last jump, e.g. a domain forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
  req.connection.remoteAddress ||
  req.socket.remoteAddress ||
  req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;

if (ip && ip.startsWith("::ffff:")) {
  ip = ip.replace("::ffff:", "")
}
```

- http://www.beforecoding.net/devtool/my/ip/address

Comment: Seems like a variant of this solution works for now. Using app.set('trust proxy') and then the last value of req.ips gives the last proxy bounce from the request. Seems like the x-forwarded-for header can be spoofed though... hopefully I can figure something else out to detect people trying to spoof the header.